# Is it OK to use dot-syntax getters within an NSManagedObject's custom class?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, key-value-observing, kvc

Generally speaking... in an NSManagedObject class, inside one of the setters for a given float dynamic property, is it OK to use the dot-syntax getters for *other* float dynamic properties of the same NSManagedObject within that setter? Or do I need to use KVC-compliant CoreData accessors *any* time I access a value, even if it's from a different method than the actual getter for the value being accessed? I would assume that calling the dot-syntax in this way would cause my other custom accessor to fire, which is OK with me, since inside that there are the proper KVC primitive accessors. But I've seemed to run into weird issues where the dot-syntax either simply fails, or seems to have unpredictable results, and I'm not sure if it's because of the fact I'm using the dot-syntax in an unsafe way, or if there's some other bug I haven't figured out yet.

Here's a code sample of something I'm talking about:

```
- (void)illTakeYouToTheWoodshed {
    float h = self.SSx.floatValue/self.yourMomsCurrentWeightInTons.floatValue;
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"SSy"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:@(h) forKey:@"SSy"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"SSy"];
    [self diagonal]; //makes sure nd gets set
}

- (void)setSSx:(NSNumber *)value{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"SSx"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:value forKey:@"SSx"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"SSx"];
    if(self.WorH==syanara || self.WorH == dude_wtf) {
        if(self.SSy.floatValue != 0.0) {
            [self doThatFunkyDance];
            [self diagonal]; 
        } else if (self.youBetcha.floatValue != 0.0) {
            [self whatTheFrakDoesThisEvenDo];
        }
    } else if (self.WorH==fooBarTastic) {
        if(self.yourMomsCurrentWeightInTons.floatValue != 0.0) {
            [self illTakeYouToTheWoodshed];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Escaped with salad not having been tossed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a code example of the setter you're talking about?

Comment: Generally speaking it's OK, but I agree, it would be good to see the actual code in question.

Comment: I also agree, that some code snippets would be great. Without this additional info i can just say that your "there's some other bug" seems to be true